# Displaying a bootstrap modal with data from a database in MVC ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm basically trying to display details of single products that are in a database using a Bootstrap Modal.

The code I have below allows me to click a product button with the details of only one of the products no matter which button I select.

Any idea where I'm going wrong. Your help is greatly appreciated. Code snippet below:

```
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            @product.ProductName
        </button>          

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4>@product.ProductName</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                        <div class="img-rounded col-md-5">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", "Products", new { id = product.ProductID})" width="150" height="150"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <p float="right">@product.ProductDescription</p>
                        </div>
                   </div>

                    <div style="margin-top:100px" class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
          </div>
}
```

Comment: you can either set a variable and increment you data-target and id value for modal pop up like this id="myModal"+i where "i" will be a variable, or on click of product make a ajax call and set details within your modal

Comment: Basically, you are duplicating the ID attribute on every single modal, and every button has the same modal target, so you'll only ever see one modal.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've basically edit the data-target to "#myModal-@(product.productID)" and it seems to be working perfectly! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try changing it to this.  Note: For this to work correctly, it assumes ProductID will NOT be duplicated.

```html
@foreach (var product in Model.Products)
{
    var sModalURL = "#myModal" + product.ProductID.ToString();
    var sModalId = "myModal" + product.ProductID.ToString();
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" 
            data-target="@sModalURL">
        @product.ProductName
    </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="@sModalId" class="modal fade" role="dialog" data-backdrop="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">

                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
                    <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4>@product.ProductName</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                        <div class="img-rounded col-md-5">
                            <img class="img-circle" src="@Url.Action("RenderImage", "Products", new { id = product.ProductID})" width="150" height="150" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <p float="right">@product.ProductDescription</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="margin-top:100px" class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
}
```